# What does $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I found it a lot at the start of proof etc. So i think it implies some kind of condition for existing.

Comment: it is a function that maps every pair of pairs of reals to a real : $f((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2))=z$

Comment: Maybe a points in the cartesian plane...

Comment: Maybe a pair of points define a vector...

Comment: What does the start of the proof say exactly?

Comment: $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @PeterSchlösser Then they are saying that $f$ is a function whose input is in $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$ and gives you an element in $\Bbb R$. For example $f((1,2),(3,4))=1+2+3+4=10$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Thanks, ok but what implications does this have ?

Comment: @PeterSchlösser I think we need more context to understand why $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$ can't just be written $\Bbb R^4$

Comment: @PeterSchlösser It might imply that familiarity with functions of several variables is a prerequisite for reading whatever follows.

Comment: @BernardMassé In my opinion the reason why $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$ is not written $\Bbb R^4$ should be apparent: the author will write $f(x,y)$ and it will mean than $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying

> $f:\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$

is the same as saying

> the function $f$ takes as input two pairs of real numbers (possibly two vectors in the plane, or something similar) and gives as output a real number

(plus or minus a few small words to make it fit grammatically in a sentence). That's all it means, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples to give you a feeling for the notation (this is too long for a comment):

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
1&f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z&  f(a)=0&\text{YES}\\ \hline
2&f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z&  f(a)=\frac{1}{2}+a&\text{NO}\\ \hline
3&f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z& f(a,b)=a+b  &\text{YES}\\ \hline
4&f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z& f(a,b)=\frac{a(a+1)b}{2}&\text{YES}\\\hline
5&f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z&f(a,b)=a&\text{NO}\\\hline
6&f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z&f(a,b)=(a,0)&\text{YES}\\\hline
7&f:\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\rightarrow \Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q&f(a,b)=(\frac{a}{2},b)&\text{YES}\\\hline
8&f:\Bbb Q^2\times\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Q&f((a,b),c)=a+bc&\text{YES}\\\hline
9&f:\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R&f((a,b),(c,d))=a+b+c^3-1+\frac{d}{2}&\text{YES}\\\hline
10&f:\Bbb R^4\rightarrow\Bbb R&f(a,b,c,d)=a+b+c^3-1+\frac{d}{2}&\text{YES}\\\hline
\end{array}$$

1. Is OK, since the every integers gets mapped to an integer.
2. Is not OK, since the output is always a fraction, for example $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, and this cannot be as $f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z$ tells us that integers gets mapped to integers.
3. OK.
4. This is actually OK, but a little bit tricky. The output $\frac{a(a+1)b}{2}$ is an integer, because either $a$ or $a+1$ has to be even.
5. Is not OK, because the notation $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ tells us that a pair of integers must map to a pair of integers, and $a$ is a single integer.
6. The problem above is fixed by having $(a,b)\mapsto (a,0)$.
7. Is OK, the output is a pair of rational numbers.
8. Is OK, the input is a pair of rational numbers $(a,b)$ and an integer $c$, with the output also being a rational number.
9. Is the same as 10., and both works.